# bought activa 125 and after 2-3 days new problems start to rise. please help and give solution since im new in this segament

Tags: honda, activa

i bought a used activa 125 and after paying and going home i noticed its odometer was not working and was stuck at same kilometers (digital) and neither its speedometer was working.

after i reach home new problems start to rise. today at present, i generally start my activa in evening and it takes atleast 30 kicks to start with or without choke. and the ideal rpm is also fluctuating rhythemically. plus the activa takes alot of stress when a pillion is sitting even if its 125cc. the accelerator wire is stucking and rpm doesnt go down even after changing whole wire. the milage is also quite less.

please help and suggest what should i do and what parts i need to get checked at service center.

thank you

Comment: You may have bought a well used Activa if the odometer and speedometer failed. Many kick starts may suggest; worn piston rings/cylinder/spark plug with lower compression. Lower than normal compression from a worn engine might feel easier to kick start than a good engine. Resistance to kick starting is one way of determining compression. Step down on the kick starter pedal slowly; high resistance suggests good compression, low to zero resistance - low compression.  Odometer/speedometer failure may be as simple as disconnected drive cable or wiring, more complicated if electronics is involved.